# SQL - Order By Different case on one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this:
[image: data]

I wanna order the data, and the result will be like this:
`CHECKING_ACCT_MONTHS`
`--------------------`
`11-2011`
`10-2011`
`09-2011`
`AVERAGE`
in another words, the data will ordered descending, but the `AVERAGE` data will be at the bottom. How can I do that,.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query should be ...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TableName
 ORDER BY 
    CASE 
      WHEN CHECKING_ACCT_MONTHS = 'AVERAGE' 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 
   END, 
   CHECKING_ACCT_MONTHS DESC
```

Comment: @ Praditha : When the answer is so helpful, why would not you award an upvote?

Comment: @ Nitin Midha : I edited for readability. Please re-check if the query is still correct :)